# How to build a locale switcher in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to build a locale switcher in Rails. I have a great number of languages to support, so I am trying to use a select box for that purpose.

```
# application.html.erb

<%= form_tag people_path, :class => 'locale' do %>
  <%= select_tag 'set_locale', options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s), :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
<% end %>


# application_controller.rb

before_filter :set_i18n_locale_from_params

def set_i18n_locale_from_params
  if params[:locale]
    if I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale].to_sym)
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || "de"
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "#{params[:locale]} translation not available"
      logger.error flash.now[:notice]
    end
  end
end

def default_url_options
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

The problem now is that when I select a language from the select box, the `create` action inside my `people_controller.rb` gets triggered for some reason.

What action would I have to put in the `form_tag` in order to get a locale switcher that works throughout the entire site?

Thanks for any help.

```
class LocalesController < ApplicationController

  def change_locale
    if params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to people_path(:locale => params[:set_locale])
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want it to happen on the People index page, try adding `:method => :get` to your `form_tag`. If you need to support the locale on multiple different pages throughout your application I would make a new controller for switching the locale (`LocalesController`) that sets the locale in the session and redirects back to the previous page. That way you can check it throughout the application.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. It looks like it is working. I just don't know how to `redirect_to` the previous page. I pasted my controller code above, maybe you can have a look.

Comment: redirect_to(request.referer), redirect_to(:back)

Comment: You should be able to use `redirect_to :back`. I would suggest using the `session` instead of passing a `param` for keeping track of the current locale. Something like `session[:locale] = params[:set_locale]` in your `LocalesController` and then just use `session[:locale]` in your `PeopleController`.

Comment: OK, I was able to get this working! Thanks a lot for your help.